# My data from my api won't display in my html (im still new to coding but here is my code)

Tags: javascript, html

```
var listApi = document.querySelector(".list-item")
var searchApi = document.getElementById("search-api")
document.querySelector("#enter").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputValue = searchApi.value; 
    fetch('https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/'     +inputValue, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then((data) => {
        var title = document.createElement("li")
        title.setAttribute = ".list-item";
        title.innerText = data;
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

});
```

//Html portion

```
<h2 class="justify-center flex">Results</h2>
<ul id="result-list">
  <li class="list-item "></li>

</ul>
```

The api works fine as it displays the data in the console, i just can figure how to get it in my html.

Comment: What kind of data does the API return? JSON that when parsed is an array, an object?

Comment: It returns a object with data that has an array. Im not sure if im saying it correctly, but when it displays in the console it says object when I click the object drop down it shows data with an array of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only missing part is how you loop over your data and add items to your list, so here's a quick example.

```js
// Cache the list element
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

// Your data will look something like this
// where `data` is an object with a property
// with an array
const data = {
  cities: [
    { name: 'London' },
    { name: 'Paris' }    
  ]
};

// Once your data has returned, loop
// over the array, and then add each new item
// to the list
for (const city of data.cities) {
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = city.name;
  ul.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

If you wanted another approach that uses more "modern" methods:

```js
// Cache the list element
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');

// Your data will look something like this
// where `data` is an object with a property
// with an array
const data = {
  cities: [
    { name: 'London' },
    { name: 'Paris' }    
  ]
};

// Create an array of HTML strings by mapping
// over the data
const html = data.cities.map(city => {
  return `<li>${city.name}</li>`;
}).join('');

// And then adding that joined string to the list
ul.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Addition information

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 1):

When you create an element with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) it exists only in memory-- it isn't actually attached to the DOM yet.  You need to insert it somewhere, like so:

```
var listApi = document.querySelector(".list-item")
var searchApi = document.getElementById("search-api")
document.querySelector("#enter").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputValue = searchApi.value; 
    fetch('https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/'     +inputValue, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then((data) => {
        var title = document.createElement("li")
        title.setAttribute = ".list-item"
        title.innerText = data;
        var list = document.getElementById("result-list");
        list.appendChild(title);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

});
```

Also note your line `title.setAttribute = ".list-item"` won't work as you expect-- you are overwriting the `setAttribute` function with a string.  Better to just use `classList` as `title.classList.add('list-item');`

**Also**, as [user Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377002/andy) points out in the comments, you have another problem with your chaining of `.then`s-- specifically, you have a `.then()` that `console.log`s the result and returns nothing.  The way promise chains work is that the next `.then` will act on the result passed from the previous `.then`; however, `.then(response => console.log(response))` will return `undefined`, so the `data` argument coming into your next `.then` will be `undefined`.  Below is a code example that fixes both the `setAttribute` issue and the `.then` issue:

```
var listApi = document.querySelector(".list-item")
var searchApi = document.getElementById("search-api")
document.querySelector("#enter").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputValue = searchApi.value; 
    fetch('https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/'     +inputValue, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
    .then((data) => {
        var title = document.createElement("li")
        title.classList.add("list-item");
        title.innerText = data;
        var list = document.getElementById("result-list");
        list.appendChild(title);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

});
```

Finally, if you are just attempting to insert a plain object or array as text into the DOM you will likely get unexpected results, such as it displaying simply as `"object Object"` in the `<li>`.  Let's presume for a moment that your response looks something like this:

```
{
    data: ['MacReady', 'Childs', 'Blair', 'Nauls', 'Clark', 'Palmer']
}
```

To write this data to the DOM, you'd need to access it at the `data` property, then map over it (either with a loop or using an array method like `.forEach`) and add each item to an element (like an `<li>` in your case) and insert it to the DOM.  Here's an example:

```
var listApi = document.querySelector(".list-item")
var searchApi = document.getElementById("search-api")
document.querySelector("#enter").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputValue = searchApi.value; 
    fetch('https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/'     +inputValue, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    })
    .then((data) => {
        let myList = data.data;

        myList.forEach(datum => {
            var title = document.createElement("li")
            title.classList.add("list-item");
            title.innerText = datum;
            var list = document.getElementById("result-list");
            list.appendChild(title);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

});
```

There are other approaches to this-- using a `for` loop, or using DOM fragments to increase performance, but something along these lines *should* work for your use case.

Comment: `.then(response => console.log(response))` is also an issue.

Comment: @Andy - ah, good point-- I'll update my answer to call that out-- thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works, just that now my html displays [object Object] and im not sure what that is

Comment: @RS - that most likely means the data you are receiving is a [JavaScript `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). It is probably an array or a plain object-- both of these are data structures that can contain information in a structured manner that allows you to easily manipulate and access the data they contain.  As a simplification, plain objects are hash maps accessed by key, whereas arrays are ordered lists.

Comment: Ultimately, if you try to push a non-string into the DOM it will get converted to a string, sometimes inelegantly. You could try doing it as `title.innerText = JSON.stringify(data);` to get a sense of what is actually contained within, but I imagine you already know this from your console log in the previous `.then`.  You will probably need to figure out what data you want to display and how to best extract it from the response.  This is most likely sufficiently different a task from the question in your post here that it may be better posted as a separate question.

Comment: @RS - Actually, [your question about "object Object" almost certainly already has several answers on SO already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55198186/6831341).

Comment: @Andy -- ah, sure, thanks, I can update that now.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I wouldn't use `map` for that as it's intended to return a new array. `forEach` or `for/of` would be better. But great answer.

Comment: @Andy Ooof-- great point. I was looking at some React code, which typically uses `.map` in JSX, and went on autopilot-- I like to think I would have caught that on PR review :D Thanks for all the double-checks!

Comment: When I try this method I keep having an error TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...myList.forEach...'

Comment: @RS - my example assumed a format for your data since you didn't provide it in your question.  If the format of your data doesn't _exactly_ match my assumption it won't work as a direct copy/paste; it was intended to provide you with enough context to extrapolate it into your own specific use case.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderNied I figured it out because of your response

Answer (score 0):

You need to update an element that is in the dom.

```
var listApi = document.querySelector(".list-item")
var searchApi = document.getElementById("search-api")
document.querySelector("#enter").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputValue = searchApi.value; 
    fetch('https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/'     +inputValue, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then((data) => {
        listApi.innerText = data;
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

});
```