# I can't figure out how to display this data in a separate line in my html from JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
  document.querySelector("#enter").addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputValue = searchApi.value; 
        fetch('https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/' +inputValue, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response =>  {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .then((data) => {

            var title = document.createElement("li")
            title.classList.add('list-item');
            title.innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
            var list = document.getElementById("result-list");
            list.appendChild(title);
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    
    });
```

HTML looks like this

```
<h2 class="justify-center flex">Results</h2>
<ul id="result-list">
  <li class="list-item "></li>

</ul>
```

Because I use JSON stringify it turns out as it did, but I want the data to be displayed one by one and not all in one line. I have tried forEach, and for loop but I don't think I did it correctly, so any help is appreciated.
[image: This is how it displays on the webpage]
[image: I want it to display as it looks in the console log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), it is a [plain object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)-- as such, you cannot simply loop over it by index like you would an array or other iterable.  If you want to get all key/value pair entries from this object into an array to iterate you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
.then((data) => {
  const myData = data.data;

  Object.entries(myData).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    var title = document.createElement("li")
    title.classList.add("list-item");
    title.innerText = `${key}: ${val}`;
    var list = document.getElementById("result-list");
    list.appendChild(title);
  });
})
```

Note that this will probably come back in alphabetical order-- if you want a specific order, you would need to adjust your approach.  You can also use the `Object.entries` approach for other solutions listed in [your original question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71768743/6831341).